# UIScrollView not scrolling with uiview

Tags: c#, iphone, uiview, xamarin, uiscrollview

I created a scrollview dynamically and populei with UIViews which are also dynamically created.
It is a calendar where each month is a view that is placed on scrollview, the problem is that does not work.
Can anyone help solve?
Thank you very much

```
double larguraTela                  = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * 0.01;
        scrollView                          = new UIScrollView(new CGRect((nfloat)larguraTela * 3, 105, (nfloat)larguraTela * 94, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height-110));
        scrollView.BackgroundColor          = UIColor.FromRGB(60, 60, 60);
        scrollView.ScrollEnabled            = true;
        scrollView.UserInteractionEnabled   = true;

        View.AddSubview(scrollView);
        scrollView.AddSubview(Calendario(1));
        scrollView.AddSubview(Calendario(2));
        scrollView.AddSubview(Calendario(3));
    }
```

```
   public UIView Calendario(int mes) {  UIView local            = new UIView(new CGRect(0, altura, scrollView.Frame.Width, 185));           local.BackgroundColor   = UIColor.FromRGB(60, 60, 60);
```

…
return local; 
}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ContentSize of the scrollview. If you are using constraints it should do it automatically so long as there is a bottom constraint. If not you need to explicitly set the ContentSize to fit the content